# Which kind of diagnostic plots for count data?

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, count-data, quasi-likelihood, poisson-binomial-distribution

I know that for an `lm` model is enough to run `plot(model_lm)` to get diagnostic plots.
I am dealing with high-dimensional count data, so I am using Poisson, Quasipoisson, Negative Binomial and Zero Inflated .
Is there a way to compare different glm outputs to see which one fit the data better? Moreover, how can I plot diagnostic plots?

My question is a bit different from: [Diagnostic plots for poisson regression(GLM)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333023/diagnostic-plots-for-poisson-regressionglm) since my X is made of five numeric variables.

Comment: Answers to the duplicate explicitly include multiple regressions (more than one explanatory variable).